# script conflict contact form, fancybox

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I have contact form problem. The form fails to deliver a message. The source of the problem is  two conflicting script libraries. Both libraries are needed for different effects.

```
The fancy box scripts works with the image display mechanism.
<script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/lib/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

The jquery scripts works with contact form mechanism
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If I remove the fancy box script the contact form works but lose the fancybox interactive image display features.

If I remove the googleapi script I loos the form functionality.

Changing the order of the scripts or loading them asynchronously has not worked.

Is the away to deal with this script conflict?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) jquery method.

> The **$other** variable now has the "**ajax google api jquery.min.js**", $other is now an alias to the jQuery function; creating the new alias is optional.
>
> The **$** variable now has the "**jquery-1.10.1.min.js**", which is a shortcut for
> **document.getElementById()**. mainDiv below is a **DOM element**, not a jQuery object.

#### solution for remove conflict in different jquery version

```
<!-- Putting jQuery into no-conflict mode. -->
<script src="./fancybox/lib/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
var $other = jQuery.noConflict();
$other(document).ready(function() {
    $other("div").hide();
});
 

window.onload = function() {
    var main = $("main");
}
 
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please advise how to implement this function. A basic question. DO I need to replace the ("div") with the id of the elemnt to hide and the ("main") with the the id of the element to load?

Comment: to avoid the conflict the form script should hide the fancybox script when he form sends the message.